# ArrayList.remove(index), is it viable for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When creating a game and you want to delete something from the screen that is in an ArrayList, lets say a bullet, is it viable to use `arrayList.remove(index)` to remove it from the game? or is it still using up memory when done this way?

If this is not the preferred way to do it, please point me in the right direction :)

Comment: this isn't game dev related

Comment: I think it is, but okey. Maybe I misunderstood the problem I'm having.

Comment: I'm not familiar with typical Java UI protocols, but I suspect that something on the screen is "held" there by links from some sort of UI "view" object.  It's vaguely possible that that object has a method named "remove", but very unlikely that the object is an ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is possibly. Removing the bullet from the `ArrayList` will eliminate a reference to it. If there are no other references, then the bullet object will be GCed eventually.

The screen of course will have to redraw itself without the bullet and that is a mostly separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

> If you **remove an object** from ArrayList, **and** that **object
>   doesn't have any other reference,** then it would be **'eligible'**
>   for the garbage collector.

After that, you need not worry about removing it from the heap: JVM would do that through automatic garbage collector.

> For the **question you asked**;
>
> or is it still using up memory when done this way?
>
> The answer is; **YES**, it will still be occupying memory unless the
>   JVM calls for garbage collection and frees the memory.

Hope that helps.